# CPT-onomies CPT_TAXONOMY->get_terms extremely slow with 6K posts

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I currently have a site with 6K posts. There are 3 CPT taxonomies that are attached to posts.

When I try to access .../wp-admin/edit.php, I'm getting the following LONG QUERY error:

```
SELECT wpposts.ID, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_postmeta wpmeta INNER JOIN wp_posts wpmetaposts ON wpmetaposts.ID = wpmeta.post_id AND wpmetaposts.post_type IN ( 'post' ) AND wpmetaposts.post_status = 'publish' WHERE wpmeta.meta_key = '_custom_post_type_onomies_relationship' AND wpmeta.meta_value = wpposts.ID ) AS count FROM wp_posts wpposts WHERE wpposts.ID IN ( '1000197','21759','21205','21204','21203','21202','21201','21200','21199','20207','20205','20200','20149','19337','19154','19139','18632','18311','18306','18304','18287','18285','18279','18277','18275','18273','18247','18086','17693','17621','17284','17134','16976','16970','16946','16759','16703','16702','16701','16699','16698','16697','16696','16695','16694','16693','16660','16299','16192','16187','16178','16176','16173','16170','16169','16160','16156','16154','16152','16054','16053','16052','15924','15890','15884','15844','15831','15672','15485','15406','15299','15196','15180','15168','15060','15005','14996','14886','14749','14681','14680','14679','14677','14662','14610','14586','14422','14421','13982','13683','13682','13666','13576','13568','13555','13553','13495','13406','13405','13399','13394','13393','13392','13390','13389','13354','13321','13319','13302','13301','13300','13299','13184','13128','13075','13071','12996','12774','12773','12308','12197','12050','12033','11782','11206','10821','10820','10816','10788','10286','10280','10279','10278','10277','10276','10275','10267','10264','8753','8482','8481','8480','8479','8478','8477','8476','8475','8445','7768','7353','6948','6900','6899','6898','6896','6895','6894','6877','6730','6611','6609','6605','6565','6372','5992','5660','5577','5510','5492','5359','5119','5004','4964','4963','4961','4919','4844','4817','4813','4531','4052','4051','4050','4048','4047','4046','4045','4044','4042','4041','4039','4038','3987','3986','3984','3983','3964','3703','3699','3540','3475','3474','3450','3430','3403','3402','3401','3336','3325','3281','3243','3234','3091','3041','2928','2900','2889','2869','2828','2826','2801','2735','2719','2703','2702','2699','2651','2632','2631','2630','2629','2568','2511','2475','2407','2386','2361','2332','2318','2300','2123','2122','2066','2042','2039','2038','2004','2003','2002','1974','1917','1856','1673','1671','1612','1532','1530','1507','1455','1452','1196','1189','1188','1128','894','893','892','891','855','854','850','609','608','548','449','286','285','241','159','146','144','141','93','92','91','85','84','73','72','71','70','69','68','67','66','65','64','63','62','61','60','59','58','57','56','55','54','53','52','51','50','49','48','47','46','45','44','43','42','41','40','39','38','37','36','35','34','33','32','31','30','29','28','27','26','25','24','23' ) AND wpposts.post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY wpposts.ID ASC
```

If I detach all but one of the taxonomies, I can get to .../wp-admin/edit.php. Query monitor shows the following stats:

> SPEED: 15.03 second load time
>
> **CPT_TAXONOMY->get_terms** 4 13.3913
>
> **CPT_TAXONOMY->wp_get_object_terms** 2 0.2535

I'm trying to figure out the best way to modify the plugin so that the query hooks don't cause the edit pages to be unreachable. If anyone out there is familiar with this plugin and might have some optimization suggestions, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: How many posts are you viewing on the edit.php screen?

Comment: 20 total. I think the issue is that the query contains an IN statement with an array of 6K IDs?